# Trying to setup a BlackJackTable, trouble with setting up my OO design

Tags: c#, arrays, composition

I'm trying to build a console app that is a blackjack game.  BlackJackTable : TableGame and has 6 BettingSpots.  I'm thinking I want to have an array that contains the BettingSpots.  But I am getting errors trying to populate the BettingSpot[].  Any advice on how to better proceed with the design would be much appreciated.

```
public abstract class TableGame
{
    // Can have 5-7 bettings spots.  Has a dealer, players, Rules
    public abstract void Rules();
    public abstract BettingSpot[] bettingSpotArray;
    public Dealer dealer = new Dealer();

}

public class BlackJackTable : TableGame
{

    // A blackjack tablegame "has a" 6 BettingSpots available that a Player chooses to occupy.  Have the Game ask the player which bettingspots they'd
    // like to place a bet on.  Bet amount must be the same for each.  Use a try catch block to make sure TotalChips >= all bets. 
    public BlackJackTable(int tableNumber)
    {
        _tableNumber = tableNumber;
    }

    public override void BlackJackRules()
    {  }

        BettingSpot spot1 = new BettingSpot(1);
        BettingSpot spot2 = new BettingSpot(2);
        BettingSpot spot3 = new BettingSpot(3);
        BettingSpot spot4 = new BettingSpot(4);
        BettingSpot spot5 = new BettingSpot(5);
        BettingSpot spot6 = new BettingSpot(6);

    public override BettingSpot[] bettingSpotArray = new BettingSpot[5];

    for (int i = 0; i < bettingSpotArray.Length; i++)
    {
        bettingSpotArray[i] = new BettingSpot[i+1];
    }

    public void QueryPlayerForBettingSpots(BettingSpot[] bettingSpotArray)
    {
        int[] BettingSpotsAvailable = new BettingSpot[5];
        for (int idx = 0; idx < 5; idx++)
            if (bettingSpotArray[idx] == 0)
                BettingSpotsAvailable[idx] 

        Console.WriteLine("Place up to 3 bets on the following available BettingSpots: {0}", bettingSpotArray.Where<BettingSpot.
    }

}

public class BettingSpot
{
    protected decimal bet = 0;
    public int _bettingSpotNumber;
    // How many spots are on the Blackjack table will determine how many seats there will be. There are six betting spots allowed, 
    // so six bettingspots are created. THere are just 6 BettingSpots available and a player can
    // occupy up to 3 BettingSpots at a time.  A bettingspot "has a" bet.  If no bet, put '0' in BettingSpotArray

    public BettingSpot(int number)
    {
        _bettingSpotNumber = number;
    }

    public Player player



    public decimal Bet
    {
        get
        {
            return bet;
        }
        set
        {
            bet = value;

    }

}
```

Comment: I think I know what the issue is - but just to make sure, what is the error you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

A few things I noticed in your code.

First, I believe you're having trouble trying to populate `bettingSpotArray[]` because you're trying to do it inside the body of the class.  You need to do it inside the body of a method or property - I'd suggest the constructor or the `Rules()` method.

Secondly, since you're not defining any code in the abstract class, you might find it easier to make the abstract class an interface and have your game classes implement the interface - that way the class will know what it has to implement, but you don't have to override everything.  If you had some sort of default logic you wanted for a majority of the game classes, then I'd agree with using an abstract class that had that base logic, and the "special" classes would override it as needed.  But that's just my take on it; you may have your own valid reasons for using an abstract class that are not readily apparent in your question.

I'm not sure the code you have posted will actually compile, but I'll give some code samples that should help you get to where you're trying to go.

```
public class BlackJackTable : TableGame
{

    // If other classes need access to this I'd set it up as public
    // property, not a public field.  If not, I'd set the field to
    // private
    public override BettingSpot[] bettingSpotArray = new BettingSpot[5];

    public BlackJackTable(int tableNumber)
    {

        // I don't see a _tableNumber field in your abstract class or your 
        // inheriting class - if you don't have that field you'll get an error
        // in the compiler
        _tableNumber = tableNumber;
    }

    // Your posted code had public override void BlackJackRules, but there is
    // no BlackJackRules() method to override
    public override void Rules()
    {  

        // These are superfulous since you'll be using an array
        // for the betting spots
        //BettingSpot spot1 = new BettingSpot(1);
        //BettingSpot spot2 = new BettingSpot(2);
        //BettingSpot spot3 = new BettingSpot(3);
        //BettingSpot spot4 = new BettingSpot(4);
        //BettingSpot spot5 = new BettingSpot(5);
        //BettingSpot spot6 = new BettingSpot(6);

        // Now you can initialize your array
        for (int i = 0; i < bettingSpotArray.Length; i++)
        {
             bettingSpotArray[i] = new BettingSpot[i+1];
        }
    }
}
```

Your `QueryPlayerForBettingSpots` doesn't make a lot of sense either, as it prompts for input from the user, but doesn't accept any input.  Perhaps you haven't finished that method?

I think your overall approach is the correct approach, but your implementation has some issues (which I've noted above).  Hopefully this will be of some help to you in moving forward in your project.